# Cannot compile application using Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE with Apache 2.4 FOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-fop

I have added Apache FOP Dependency as below. Which I have added for PDF generation.

compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.4" After that i am getting Error in gradle build the Service.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>   Could not find javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3.
>        Required by:
>            project : > org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.4 > org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-core:2.4
>   Could not find com.sun.media:jai-codec:1.1.3.
>        Required by:
>            project : > org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.4 > org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop-core:2.4
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 7s
>   2 actionable tasks: 2 executed**

Comment: compile "org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-api:4.3.1"
    compile "org.apache.avalon.framework:avalon-framework-impl:4.3.1"
    compile "javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3"
    compile "com.sun.media:jai-codec:1.1.3"
    compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.4"   build.gradle changes

Answer (score 0):

The missing dependencies are probably located in a repository that is not included in your build-file. Using gradle, I added this to the repositories block:

```
jcenter()
maven {
    url="https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/"
}
```